# Parsing Liquid in a Jekyll generator before converting to JSON

Tags: ruby, json, generator, jekyll, liquid

Best to start by saying that I am very new to Ruby and Liquid. I have searched around looking for some resource on this issue, but as yet haven't been able to find anything of real use.

I have a Jekyll site, which utilises the HTML5 History API. I have a Jekyll generator plugin which creates a single JSON file which holds all the post and page content, ready for use with HTML5 PushState and PopState. This part is functioning properly and is tested.

My problem comes when I have a post/page on the site which has Liquid tags in it. I am guessing I need to parse these Liquid tags to get the template output before I create my JSON object for each post/page. Here is what I have for pages as an example:

```
# Iterate over all pages
site.pages.each do |page|

# Encode the page HTML content to JSON
link = page.url
    @content = Liquid::Template.parse(page.content)
    hash[link] = { "body_class" => page.data['body_class'], "content" => converter.convert(@content.render), "title" => '<h1>' + page.data["content_title"] + '</h1>' }
end
```

Now, this at the minute is basically removing all Liquid tags from the generated JSON file, leaving nothing in it's place.

Here is my full generator file on [Github](https://github.com/Huskie/darrenhuskie.com/blob/master/_plugins/generate_json.rb) which is based very heavily on [nice work by Jezen Thomas](https://github.com/jezen/jekyll-backbone).

The output JSON file is also in that repo with the site, or can be accessed quickly [here](https://github.com/Huskie/darrenhuskie.com/blob/master/_site/content/content.json). The blog.html content is the last item in the JSON file and shows the empty h1 and div tags which should have content.

Comment: i think you need to bind some scope to the liquid template so that it can render what ever you pass in there.